# Modal-Overlay issue

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

First of all excuse me for explanation if I am not up to the mark, as this is my first post in this platform, Well, I am working on overlay where it has to be shown in right side of the page with given width of say 416px and 100vh of height, but things are getting cut if I do decrease the browser window and as I am decreasing the size of the browser window the button at bottom start appearing on content of overlay which has to remain at bottom even the height is getting decreased, here is the my code as below:

```css
.advanced-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(35, 0, 18, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100002;
  top: -41px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  .advance-overlay-footer {
      display:flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items:center;
      position: fixed;
      right: 24px;
      width:156px;
      bottom: 24px;
      height:6%;
    }
  .advanced-overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    // min-height: 83vh;
    width: 416px;
    margin-top: 108px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 6px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100004;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    background-color: #f5f4f6;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07),
      0 19px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05),
      0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04), 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
   
    .close-advance-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 110px;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 5px 22px;
      top: -18px;
      right: 155px;
      opacity: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
      img {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        align-self: center;
      }
      .button-text {
        align-self: center;
        margin-left: 5px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000000;
      }
    }
    .advnaced-overlay-content-secion {
      //min-height:89vh;
      width: 100%;
      bottom:10%;
      // height:100vh;

      .select-box {
        margin-top: 40px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
      }

      .accordinan-filter {
        margin-bottom: 24px;
      }
      .accordian-title {
        font-weight: 900;
      }
      .accordian-content {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    }
  }
   
}
.is-maximum {
  height: 73vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;


  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="advanced-overlay" v-if="toggleFilter">
    <div class="advanced-overlay-content">
        <div class="close-advance-overlay" @click="toggleAdvanceFilterOverlay">
            <img class src="../assets/icons/close.svg" />
            <span class="button-text">Close</span>
        </div>
        <div class="advnaced-overlay-content-secion is-maximum">
            <div class="select-box"></div>
            <div class="accordinan-filter"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="advance-overlay-footer">...two buttons</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I what I would like to achieve eventually is that, I want respsonsive overlay at right side of the browser window, provided if I am decreasing height of the browser the buttons at bottom should stay there (fixed position) and content should be within limit of .advnaced-overlay-content-secion

Answer (score 0):

for a responsive design I recommend you to read into the use of grid and espacially for mobile designs also the use of @media breakpoints.

for having some thing to stick at the bottom simply use:
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;

Comment: I already did that and also I know about break point, please try to help not just pointing to something.

Comment: then please provide the entire code which will help to understand what you trying to achieve. all we have currently is a grey page with a the text: 2 buttons. also you run a js snippet with the accordian I guess. would also be really helpfull if you include this